# How to hide/disable/remove navigation bar back button or hide status bar from apple watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to to hide/disable/remove navigation bar back button on an Apple Watch.
Also trying to hide status bar.

I push a new `InterfaceController` like:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"applewatch" context:nil];
```

Anyone have any idea how to hide/disable/remove navigation bar or hide status bar from Apple Watch?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019256/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-back-button/30907556#30907556

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to hide native navigation controls currently, so I am using reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts: and passing any persistent app state via the context, which I then pass back to the previous controller when navigating back. This will show a page loading animation instead of a push slide animation, but it works.

In controller 1:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    if (context) {
        // Restore state from context and update any UI
        [self.controllerVar1 = context objectForKey:@"controllerVar1"];
        [self.controllerVar2 = context objectForKey:@"controllerVar2"];
    }
}

// Call from method that is initiating navigation
[Controller1 reloadRootControllerWithNames:@[ @"Controller2" ] contexts:@[ @{ @"controllerVar1" : self.controllerVar1, @"controllerVar2" : self.controllerVar2 } ]];
```

In controller 2:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    self.previousControllerState = context;
}

- (void)navigateBack {
    [Controller2 reloadRootControllerWithNames:@[ @"Controller1" ] contexts:@[self.previousControllerState]];

}
```