# How to hide the back button from the status bar on the Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, segue, watchkit

I want to hide the back button from my Apple Watch app from the status bar.

I used the programmable segue to navigate. But I want to to hide/disable the back button. Is it possible?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019256/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-back-button/30907556#30907556

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(
     ["myInterfaceController"], contexts: []
)
```

Where `myInterfaceController` is the identifier of the destination Interface Controller.

Thanks to Harvant for the pointer.

Comment: Since watchOS 4.0 it is ```WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["myInterfaceController"], contexts: nil, orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)```

Answer (score 2):

In WatchOS 6, there's an option on the Storyboard to set the Interface Controller to `Full Screen`.

Select the `Interface Controller` in `Storyboard` you want to hide the back button from, and in the right panel you'll see a check for `Full Screen`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs for `WKInterfaceController`, you'll see there's no API to accomplish what you're looking for: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/

The best you can do is change the text of the title/button or adjust the tint color.

Comment: It was correct two years ago, but fair play — it's no longer correct. @AshleyMills

Answer (score 0):

You can present an interface controller modally using the method `presentControllerWithName`. Then, in the interface controller called, just set the title with the method `setTitle`.

Comment: i am done with presentControllerWithName and I have use self.setTitle(""), but still i am not able to hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

#### On watchOS 5 an above

Replace pushController with below code

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["myInterfaceController"], contexts: nil, orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)
```